# Server not getting message emitted with client - NestJS MQTT

Tags: nestjs

I'm new to Nest and I'm trying to integrate the MQTT protocol. Everything works just fine, except that the server doesn't get any message emitted from the client instantiated on the server.

**`main.ts`**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  // Create regular nest application.
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Then combine it with your microservice
  const mqtt = app.connectMicroservice({
    transport: Transport.MQTT,
    options: {
      url: 'brokerUrl',
      clientId: 'id',
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }
  });

  await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**`AppModule.ts`**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'MQ_CLIENT',
        transport: Transport.MQTT,
        options: {
            url: 'brokerUrl',
            clientId: 'id',
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        }
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**`AppController.ts`**

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  @EventPattern('test')
  getNotifications(data) {
    console.log(data); // nothing is received
  }


  @Get('/')
  test() {
    // send a message when accessing route /
    this.appService.sendMessage();
  }
}
```

**`AppService.ts`**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(@Inject('MQ_CLIENT') private client: ClientProxy){
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    console.log('connecting');
    await this.client.connect();
    console.log('connected');
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.client.emit('test', 'some data');
  }
}
```

The message is correctly sent to the broker but it is not received in the nest server which should be subscribed to. If messages are sent from other client (outside of nest) they are received.

Comment: What server are you using for messaging? RabbitMQ? Kafka?

Comment: I'm using Mosquitto